# Implement property read and read&write for fields of an array of records, inside a class

Tags: arrays, class, delphi, properties, records

I would like to know if I can create an array of records in a class, where some fields are read-only properties, while others are for read and write.

I could think an example like this:

```
unit clsCustomers;

interface

uses
  Classes;

type

  TUnitsCategory = (type1, type2, type3, type4);

  TCustomer = record
    ID       : LongWord;
    name     : string[25];
    surname  : string[25];
    category : TUnitsCategory;
  end;
  TCustomers = array of TCustomer;

  CCustomers = class
    private
      mycustomers : TCustomers;
    protected
    ...
    published
      property customer[index: LongWord]: TCustomers           //
        read mycustomer[index].ID;                             // <-- just to say...
        read mycustomer[index].name  write mycustomer[index].name; // 

  end;
```

Here we have an array of customers, that I want to be accessible through the instance of this class...

I read about how to implement an [array property](http://delphi.cjcsoft.net/viewthread.php?tid=43739) and I wondered if I would like to have the "ID" field as read only, whereas other fields accessible in read and write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the closest you can get is something like this:

```
CCustomers = class
private
  mycustomers : TCustomers;
public
  property customerID[index: LongWord]: LongWord read mycustomers[index].ID;                            
  property customerName[index: LongWord] read mycustomers[index].name write mycustomers[index].name;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

I got this error: "[dcc32 Error] clsCustomers.pas(26): E2188 Published property 'customerID' cannot be of type ARRAY"

Comment: Sorry, it needs to be public instead. If you need design-time access, use a TCollection.